# Difficulty Removing Div Element Via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having some trouble removing an element that gets added dynamically to the DOM.  Everything in the script below works as it is supposed to, with the exception of the remove method inside the mouseleave handler.  My guess is that I'm making a mistake with the CSS selector, but I'm not sure what it is.  Any help will be much appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function ()
        {
            $('#myTr').mouseenter(function ()
            {
                var cell1 = $(this).children(':first');
                cell1.css('position', 'relative');
                var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
                var myChildDiv = document.createElement('div');
                myChildDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
                myChildDiv.style.height = '20px';
                myChildDiv.style.width = '30px';
                myChildDiv.style.opacity = '0.6';
                myChildDiv.style.background = 'grey';
                $(cell1).prepend(myDiv);
                $(myDiv).append(myChildDiv);
            })
            .mouseleave(function ()
            {
                $(this).remove('td:first-child>div');
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="myTr">
            <td style="width: 200px;">
                Anytown, MA
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could place the element you create into a variable in the scope of your function and then simply call remove() on it... This has the added benefit of not needing to use css selectors to find it again.

```
    $(function ()
    {
        var myDiv;
        $('#myTr').mouseenter(function ()
        {
            var cell1 = $(this).children(':first');
            cell1.css('position', 'relative');
            myDiv = document.createElement('div');
            var myChildDiv = document.createElement('div');
            myChildDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
            myChildDiv.style.height = '20px';
            myChildDiv.style.width = '30px';
            myChildDiv.style.opacity = '0.6';
            myChildDiv.style.background = 'grey';
            $(cell1).prepend(myDiv);
            $(myDiv).append(myChildDiv);
        })
        .mouseleave(function ()
        {
            $(myDiv).remove();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
$("td:first > div", $(this)).remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd just use jQuery's object creation:

```
var cell1 = $(this).children(':first');
cell1.css('position', 'relative');

var myDiv = $('<div />');
var myChildDiv = $('<div />');

myChildDiv.css({
  'position': 'absolute',
  'height': '20px',
  'width': '30px',
  'opacity': '0.6',
  'background-color': 'grey'
});

$(cell1).prepend(myDiv);
$(myDiv).append(myChildDiv);
```

And use this `mouseleave`:

```
$('td:first > div', this).remove();
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations!  I don't often use that syntax, but it looks a lot cleaner than what I wrote!

Comment: Just a matter of convention. The only difference is that I create a jQuery object (so you can assign a `.click()` event to it). DOM element objects' don't do that unless you wrap them in the jQuery function `$()`.

Answer (score 1):

try making it live

```
.live('mouseleave', function ()
{
  $(this).remove('td:first-child>div');
});
```

The DOM is dynamically generated, so the live will grab it when it's made

Answer (score 1):

There are occasional gotchas and caveats when trying to traverse the DOM using jQuery's child relations. For example, even if it's not actually present there is always a TBODY element encompassing the inner information of a table. Consequently I try to avoid situations where I have to worry about this kind of thing. Since you're dealing with what is essentially a mouse hover situation it might be easier to just save your myChildDiv element to a global variable and then simply call myChildDiv.remove() on the mouseleave event.

**EDIT:** Looks like zzzrByte already recommended this but I'll leave my answer simply because it describes what might be causing the issue in the first place.